# Figwheel working on Firefox but not on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, clojurescript, leiningen, figwheel

The same application that I am developing works fine on Firefox but not on Chrome.

- My application a day ago printed some things on the console, but I removed them today, which means that the actualized version of the application does not print *anything* on the console.
- On Firefox it works, everything renders and there is not prints on the console.
- However on Chrome, the app *still* prints on the console. It means that it is retaining some old state for some reason.

Does that even make sense? The code is already gone (erased), so the only way Chrome is printing the old state on the console is if he is storing it.

On Chrome I also get errors of undefined functions, but they **are** defined. On Firefox that does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading the page? Another thing to try to really get rid of the state that the browser is obviously holding onto is to clear the browser cache.

Comment: I tried reloading but the error persists. I will try clearing the cache. But is not very convenient

Comment: My experience is that you don't often have to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Try disable plugins or run in private mode.